# How to import interface from type definitions (`.d.ts`) if it has generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Here is the type definitions for [gulp-intercept](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-intercept) for the moment of asking this question:

```js
/// <reference types="node" />

import Vinyl = require('vinyl');

declare namespace intercept {
    interface Intercept {
        (interceptFunction: InterceptFunction): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
    }

    interface InterceptFunction {
        (file: Vinyl): Vinyl;
    }
}

declare var intercept: intercept.Intercept;

export = intercept;
```

Typings for Vynil allows to define custom properties. So, there will not be the TypeScript error if we write something like `file.customProperty = 1` inside intercept function. However, for autocomplete, I want to extend Vynyl interface and rewrite types like:

```js
import Vinyl = require('vinyl');

declare namespace intercept {
    interface Intercept<VinylFile__PossiblyWithCustomProperties extends Vinyl> {
        (interceptFunction: InterceptFunction<VinylFile__PossiblyWithCustomProperties>): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
    }

    interface InterceptFunction<VinylFile__PossiblyWithCustomProperties extends Vinyl> {
        (file: VinylFile__PossiblyWithCustomProperties): VinylFile__PossiblyWithCustomProperties;
    }
}

declare var intercept: intercept.Intercept;

export = intercept;
```

There is the error in line `declare var intercept: intercept.Intercept`:

```
TS2314: Generic type `VinylFile__PossiblyWithCustomProperties` requires 1 argument(s).
```

Here, we don't know, which `Vynil` superset will be used, so I am not sure that `declare var intercept: intercept.Intercept<Vynil>`; will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if I have understood the case fully, but if you just want the example to compile, annotate the type parameter `VinylFile__PossiblyWithCustomProperties` (renamed to `T` down under) at the function level of `Intercept` and not as part of the top-level interface declaration:

```
import Vinyl = require("vinyl");

declare namespace intercept {
  interface Intercept {
    // annotate type parameter T directly at function
    <T extends Vinyl>(interceptFunction: InterceptFunction<T>): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
  }

  interface InterceptFunction<T extends Vinyl> {
    (file: T): T;
  }
}

declare var intercept: intercept.Intercept;

export = intercept;
```

Example invocation in a client:

```
type ExtendedFile = Vinyl & { foo: string };

declare const callback: (file: ExtendedFile) => ExtendedFile;

intercept(callback);
```